# mavros global_position topic not publishing

Tags: ros, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am having problem getting the message published in global_position.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Ros Indigo and recently just updated the firmware. I use a pixhawk and 3DR Iris in Hexacopter .

The code I type is

**roslaunch mavros px4.launch '**

---

***The code displayed is***

NODES
/
mavros (mavros/mavros_node)

auto-starting new master

process[master]: started with pid [3595]

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to ed737cc2-9f24-11e5-83d8-605718672f0f

process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3608]

started core service [/rosout]

process[mavros-2]: started with pid [3626]

[1449741666.104377421]: FCU URL: /dev/ttyUSB0:57600

[1449741666.104555512]: serial0: device: /dev/ttyUSB0 @ 57600 bps

[1449741666.105267158]: GCS bridge disabled

[1449741666.154539806]: Plugin 3dr_radio loaded and initialized

[1449741666.157176084]: Plugin actuator_control loaded and initialized

[1449741666.217227733]: Plugin cam_imu_sync loaded and initialized

[1449741666.222946947]: Plugin command loaded and initialized

[1449741666.222998441]: Plugin distance_sensor blacklisted

[1449741666.231158700]: Plugin ftp loaded and initialized

**[1449741666.239332817]: Plugin global_position loaded and initialized**

[1449741666.239387002]: Plugin image_pub blacklisted

[1449741666.247220114]: Plugin imu_pub loaded and initialized

[1449741666.252494646]: Plugin local_position loaded and initialized

[1449741666.253141818]: Plugin manual_control loaded and initialized

[1449741666.257820893]: Plugin mocap_pose_estimate loaded and initialized

[1449741666.260583402]: Plugin param loaded and initialized

[1449741666.265841892]: Plugin px4flow loaded and initialized

[1449741666.269734947]: Plugin rc_io loaded and initialized

[1449741666.269771846]: Plugin safety_area blacklisted

[1449741666.273443314]: Plugin setpoint_accel loaded and initialized

[1449741666.287483356]: Plugin setpoint_attitude loaded and initialized

[1449741666.294109082]: Plugin setpoint_position loaded and initialized

[1449741666.296996159]: Plugin setpoint_velocity loaded and initialized

[1449741666.303087932]: Plugin sys_status loaded and initialized

[1449741666.306440053]: Plugin sys_time loaded and initialized

[1449741666.308519130]: Plugin vfr_hud loaded and initialized

[1449741666.308563956]: Plugin vibration blacklisted

[1449741666.316395234]: Plugin vision_pose_estimate loaded and initialized

[1449741666.319969704]: Plugin vision_speed_estimate loaded and initialized

[1449741666.324673530]: Plugin waypoint loaded and initialized

[1449741666.324723511]: Autostarting mavlink via USB on PX4

[1449741666.324750426]: Built-in SIMD instructions: SSE, SSE2

[1449741666.324762062]: Built-in MAVLink dialect: ardupilotmega

[1449741666.324772216]: MAVROS started. MY ID [1, 240], TARGET ID [1, 1]

[1449741666.351006806]: IMU: High resolution IMU detected!

[ WARN] [1449741666.639253535]: GP: No GPS fix

[1449741666.856344156]: CON: Got HEARTBEAT, connected.

[ WARN] [1449741666.884248232]: TM: Clock skew detected (-1449739987.504302740 s). Hard syncing clocks.

[1449741667.079375489]: IMU: High resolution IMU detected!
[ WARN] [1449741668.860667646]: VER: broadcast request timeout, retries left 4

[ WARN] [1449741669.860660935]: VER: broadcast request timeout, retries left 3

[ WARN] [1449741670.858431782]: VER: unicast request timeout, retries left 2

[1449741671.533192816]: VER: 1.1: Capabilities 0x00000000000004eb

[1449741671.533260446]: VER: 1.1: Flight software:     00000000 (424f4a9066e2b15b)

[1449741671.533303952]: VER: 1.1: Middleware software: 00000000 (424f4a9066e2b15b)

[1449741671.533338025]: VER: 1.1: OS software:         00000000 (0000000000000000)

[1449741671.533371047]: VER: 1.1: Board hardware:      00000000

[1449741671.533403720]: VER: 1.1: VID/PID: 26ac:0011

[1449741671.533436068]: VER: 1.1: UID: 3432470a38383538

[ WARN] [1449741676.886523092]: TM: Clock skew detected (-0.026125061 s). Hard syncing clocks.

[1449741682.105836631]: WP: mission received

[1449741682.647143358]: FCU: WPM: mission is empty

[ERROR] [1449741682.797194698]: FCU: REJ. WP CMD: partner id mismatch

[ WARN] [1449741686.925906789]: TM: Clock skew detected (0.121658476 s). Hard syncing clocks.

---

After that I type in

**rostopic list**

### The info displayed are

/diagnostics

/mavlink/from

/mavlink/to

/mavros/actuator_control

/mavros/battery

/mavros/cam_imu_sync/cam_imu_stamp

/mavros/global_position/compass_hdg

/mavros/global_position/global

/mavros/global_position/local

/mavros/global_position/raw/fix

/mavros/global_position/raw/gps_vel

/mavros/global_position/rel_alt

/mavros/imu/atm_pressure

/mavros/imu/data

/mavros/imu/data_raw

/mavros/imu/mag

/mavros/imu/temperature

/mavros/local_position/local

/mavros/manual_control/control

/mavros/mission/waypoints

/mavros/mocap/pose

/mavros/px4flow/ground_distance

/mavros/px4flow/raw/optical_flow_rad

/mavros/px4flow/temperature

/mavros/radio_status

/mavros/rc/in

/mavros/rc/out

/mavros/rc/override

/mavros/setpoint_accel/accel

/mavros/setpoint_attitude/att_throttle

/mavros/setpoint_attitude/attitude

/mavros/setpoint_attitude/cmd_vel

/mavros/setpoint_position/local

/mavros/setpoint_velocity/cmd_vel

/mavros/state

/mavros/time_reference

/mavros/vfr_hud

/mavros/vision_pose/pose

/mavros/vision_speed/speed_vector

/mavros/wind_estimation

/rosout

/rosout_agg

/tf

/tf_static

---

**But when I type in
rostopic echo /mavros/global_position/local
there is nothing displaying out same go to other topic in global_position except for  global_position/raw/fix and global_position/raw/gps_vel**

which the code is shown below

---

header:

seq: 594

stamp:

secs: 1449742645

nsecs: 599718628

frame_id: fcu

status:

status: -1

service: 1

latitude: 0.0

longitude: 0.0

altitude: -17.0

position_covariance: [-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

position_covariance_type: 0

---

May I know why is there still missing messages publishing in global_position where the  Plugin global_position loaded and initialized has been successful?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222290/mavros-global_position-topic-not-publishing/) by [newtoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25293/newtoros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You do not have GPS Fix.

Tip: see diagnostics first before asking questions!

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2015-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [newtoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25293/newtoros/) on 2015-12-28**:
Even with GPS fix, I am only able to get message published to global_position/raw/gps_vel and global_position/raw/fix but other global_position topics  such as global_position/compass_hdg,global_position/rel_alt,global_position/global and global_position/local have no messages published out.

**Comment by [newtoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25293/newtoros/) on 2015-12-28**:
The following is the roslaunch full output

http://pastebin.com/yqRBepPk

**Comment by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) on 2015-12-28**:\

1. Pixhawk USB only for ground maintenance and tests. Read about SYS_COMPANION parameter and TELEM2.
2. Anyway problem on FCU side. Check streams configuration (extras.txt & rc)
3. `FCU: WPM` is usual on PX4 with empty mission list.
4. `rostopic echo -n1 /diagnostics`

**Comment by [newtoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25293/newtoros/) on 2016-01-05**:
Sorry you are right, I need to have a GPS fix in order to get all messages published out in global message but the weird thing is through direct usb connection with the use of (roslaunch mavros px4.launch) I cannot get all the messages published in global_position even with GPS fix.

**Comment by [newtoros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25293/newtoros/) on 2016-01-05**:
But through indirect connection with the use of 3DR antenna(roslaunch mavros px4.launch fcu_url:='/dev/ttyUSB0:57600'), I am able to get all the messages published in global_position, thanks a lot.

**Comment by [soloros](https://answers.ros.org/users/29383/soloros/) on 2017-02-16**:
@newtoros I have been working with the 3dr solo as well and I have the same problem. When connected directly with a usb, some of the data is not published. Can you give some more detail on how you did it through the "indirect connection with 3dr antenna"? Thanks!